How to access image files sent usingajax in django backend using
I'm having a problem with sending files from ajax to django.
I collect template form using new formData() and append additional data to it, then i try to submit using ajax. On submission, i print out the submitted data in web console and i clearly see keys corresponding to dictionary containing the names of chosen images (images collected in form using input tag) and i also see other string data but when it reaches django end i print json.loads(request.body) and i only see the string data while the keys that corresponded to images are now empty dictionaries . And also request.FILES is empty.
template form
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="set_table(event)" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="sections1" name="titre">
            <label for="title">Nom du projet</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" required class="postgrid" style="width:250px;">
        </div>
        <div class="sections1">
            <label for="cathegorie">Choisissez la cathegorie qui correspond au projet</label>
            <select class="postgrid" name="cathegorie" >
                {% for cats in cat %}
                    <option value="{{ cats}}">{{ cats }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="sections" name="pb">
            <label for="probleme">Problem cible par le projet</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="probleme" required class="postgrid" data-name="probleme_name"></textarea>
            <div name="shower" id="show" class="rowbench"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sections" name="ds">
            <label for="description">Description du projet</label>
            <textarea rows="30" cols="40" name="description" data-name="description_name" required class="postgrid"></textarea>
            <div name="shower" id="show" class="rowbench"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sections" name="sv">
            <label for="services">Service creer par le projet</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="services" required data-name="services_name" class="postgrid"></textarea>
            <div name="shower" id="show" class="rowbench"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sections1" name="titre">
            <table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; margin:auto; width:80%;" id="table">
                <tbody id="tb">
                    <tr name="head">
                        <th>Personnel</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Pour</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" style="margin:auto; width:95%;" placeholder="ex:Data Analyst" id="personnel"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="margin:auto;width:95%;" placeholder="eg: 5" id="number"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" style="margin:auto;width:95%;" placeholder="eg:collecte et traitement des donnees" id="for"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button style="color:rgb(32, 148, 171); 
                            background-color:black; 
                            position:absolute; 
                            right:10px;
                            bottom:10px;" onclick="add_row(event)">&plus;</button>
        </div>
        <button Class="post_creator"  style="position:relative; bottom:4px; margin:85px; " type="submit">ENVOYER</button>
    </form>
    <script src="{% static 'projectcreation.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        arr=document.querySelectorAll('.sections');
        for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            let a=arr[i];
            a.innerHTML+=`
                        <div style="position: relative;">
                            <div style="width:40px; 
                                        height: 35px; ">
                                                <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="invisible" multiple oninput="showinput(event)" name="${a.getAttribute('name')}_image" data-name="${a.getAttribute('name')}">
                                        </div>
                            <img src="{% static 'im.png' %}" class="pinner">
                        </div>`;
            //console.log(a.getAttribute('name'));
        }
    </script>

js code
function accept(formdata){
    
    const data1=Object.fromEntries(formdata.entries());
    console.log(data1);//prints all content and i see image names in it
    $.ajax(
        {type:'POST',
        url:document.getElementById('url').getAttribute('data-url'),
        data:JSON.stringify({"formdata":data1}),
        headers:{
            "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRFToken":getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
        success:(data) =>{
            console.log('data');
        },
        dataType:'json',
        contentType:false,
        processData:false
    }
    );
}

function set_table(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const table = document.getElementById('tb');
    const list=table.children;
    console.log(list.length);
    let arr=[];
    for (let row =0; row<list.length;row++ ){
        let rows=list[row];
        if (rows.getAttribute('name') !='head'){
            let data={
                "agent":rows.querySelector('#personnel').value,
                "number":rows.querySelector('#number').value ,
                "work":rows.querySelector('#for').value
            };
            arr.push(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        
    }
    //console.log(event.target.data);
    const formdata=new FormData(event.target);
    formdata.append('tab',arr);
    accept(formdata);
    
}

django views
def project_creation_page(request):
    context={"cat":project_cat}
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax:
        print(34)
        if request.method=='POST':
            data=json.loads(request.body)
            print(data)
            for file ,files in request.FILES:
                print(file, files.name)#nothing is printed
    return render(request,"Projectscreation.html",context)

data printed in web console
{csrfmiddlewaretoken: 'g74kJdKBuemLDoIkkEzkZJ6T4b7EAAzBzMgaKn6qhcD224xHlyrhVJaYTGC552gy', title: 'all for one', cathegorie: 'Projet web', probleme: 'one for all', pb_image: File, …}
cathegorie
: 
"Projet web"
csrfmiddlewaretoken
: 
"g74kJdKBuemLDoIkkEzkZJ6T4b7EAAzBzMgaKn6qhcD224xHlyrhVJaYTGC552gy"
description
: 
"bankai"
ds_image
: 
File {name: '', lastModified: 1728416012252, lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 08 2024 20:33:32 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 0, …}
pb_image
: 
File {***name: '1718940148812.jpg'***, lastModified: 1718940577000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Jun 21 2024 04:29:37 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 10404, …}
probleme
: 
"one for all"
services
: 
"tensa zangetsu"
sv_image
: 
File {name: '', lastModified: 1728416012253, lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 08 2024 20:33:32 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 0, …}
tab
: 
"{\"agent\":\"dfdsf\",\"number\":\"cv\",\"work\":\"csdvfds\"}"
title
: 
"all for one"

pb_image contains an image
you notice this line:
pb_image
: 
File {***name: '1718940148812.jpg'***, lastModified: 1718940577000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Jun 21 2024 04:29:37 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 10404, …}

data printed in terminal. pb_image is now empty dictionary
{'formdata': {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'g74kJdKBuemLDoIkkEzkZJ6T4b7EAAzBzMgaKn6qhcD224xHlyrhVJaYTGC552gy', 'title': 'all for one', 'cathegorie': 'Projet web', 'probleme': 'one for all', 'pb_image': {}, 'description': 'bankai', 'ds_image': {}, 'services': 'tensa zangetsu', 'sv_image': {}, 'tab': '{"agent":"dfdsf","number":"cv","work":"csdvfds"}'}}

please any help will be really appreaciated. If you think any necessayry info is lacking please let me know so that i can add it

I found the solution. The problem was from my ajax code i had to cahangge it to the following
function accept(formdata){
    
    const data1=Object.fromEntries(formdata.entries());
    console.log(data1);
    $.ajax(
        {type:'POST',
        url:document.getElementById('url').getAttribute('data-url'),
        data:formdata,//this line changed
        headers:{
            "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRFToken":getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
        success:(data) =>{
            console.log('data');
        },
        dataType:'json',
        processData:false,
        contentType:false
        
    }
    );
}

